# How to convert data:image/png to SVG code?

Tags: html, svg

**Hello**,
I need to convert this data into SVG code here so I can use it in html?

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAIAAACRXR/mAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAIGNIUk0AAHolAACAgwAA+f8AAIDpAAB1MAAA6mAAADqYAAAXb5JfxUYAAABnSURBVHja7M5RDYAwDEXRDgmvEocnlrQS2SwUFST9uEfBGWs9c97nbGtDcquqiKhOImLs/UpuzVzWEi1atGjRokWLFi1atGjRokWLFi1atGjRokWLFi1af7Ukz8xWp8z8AAAA//8DAJ4LoEAAlL1nAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

I tried different online converters, but I couldn't get the SVG code from it

```
<svg></svg>
```

**Could anyone help me?**

**EDIT:**

It is from this example: [codepen](https://codepen.io/kootoopas/pen/reyqg)

Comment: What is it? A rounded rectangle? (If so, use a `<rect rx="…" />`.)

Comment: Updated - added codepen

Comment: Why do you need SVG? Isn't the png image good enough?

Comment: I want to style it for different themes and the whole project is in pure SVG and I would like to have this as well.

Answer (score 0):

PNG's are raster graphics, and SVG's are vector graphics. There is no direct way to convert a raster graphic to a vector graphic (some tools can do approximate tracing). Here is a handmade SVG which can replace your original PNG. Implementation [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QeEEoO).

```
    d="M 2.00,0.5
    C 2.00,0.50 49.00,0.50 49.00,0.50M 0.50,2
    C 0.50,2.00 0.50,49.00 0.50,49.00" />
  <path id="Corners"
    fill="none"
    stroke="black"
    stroke-width="1"
    d="M 0.00,0.00

       C 0.00,0.00 2.00,2.00 2.00,2.00M 49.00,2.00
       C 49.00,2.00 49.98,1.02 50.00,1.00M 1.00,50.00
       C 1.00,50.00 2.00,49.00 2.00,49.00M 49.00,49.00

       C 49.00,49.00 50.00,50.00 50.00,50.00" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to change colors dynamically and that's not how it works. Only in pure SVG code.

Comment: I understand now; will edit my response momentarily.

Comment: Would it be possible not to put it separately in CSS, but to paste it as HTML <svg>? Make it a pattern?